# TypeLoadExeception calling Class Library from Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I am working with a .net 4.5 Web API project (Project #1) and I am getting a weird error.  Originally everything was built into one project. I have found that I want to break the Business Logic (Project BLL) into a separate class library so that it can be reused in other projects.  I have gone through the process of breaking it apart and have found that it works from Project #2.  When I try and run Project #1 I have a weird issue where I am getting a TypeLoadException in the Application_Start when I try and call a function in Project BLL.  I call this same function in Project #2 without a problem.  The issue seems to only be in Project #1 which worked fine before the split.  The exact error message I am getting is:

```
Could not load type 'Project.BLL.Mappers.v1.AutoMapperConfiguration' from assembly 'Project.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Within Project #1 I am able to use Intelesense and F12 (Go To Definition) to see that the two projects appear to be wired up correctly.  Any thoughts?

**Update:**
Here is the entire stack trace.  It does not hit the breakpoint in the Global.asax.cs so I can't really get to the inner exception:

```
 [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Project.BLL.Mappers.v1.AutoMapperConfiguration' from assembly 'Project.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   Project.BLL.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in d:\Solutions\Project_1\Global.asax.cs:58

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Project.BLL.Mappers.v1.AutoMapperConfiguration' from assembly 'Project.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12864365
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Project.BLL.Mappers.v1.AutoMapperConfiguration' from assembly 'Project.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881108
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12722297
```

Comment: There's probably more information about *why* the runtime can't load the type in the `InnerException`.

Comment: Are these all the same .NET version?

Comment: Adam - I have added the stack trace information above

Comment: Garrison - Both projects are set to .NET 4.5

Comment: whats the type of the working project? create an empty web api project only use automapper and see if same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

check project configuration and make sure both projects target the same framework and platform (eg. Any Cpu)

Comment: Both of the projects are setup for .NET 4.5 and Any CPU